# Which page should I include the Google+ login script within?

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I'm looking at Step 2 of this: `https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/add-button`.  Should I put that in the body of the main page or in the body of the log-in form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the body of the page that contains the button.